# Grub not booting manjaro when it is clearly installed

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, manjaro

I have manjaro as a second OS in my pc, I recently reinstalled it because of problems with something I don't know after the update, it didn't give me any video signal after I selected it from grub, now that I reinstalled it and perfectly know that it's installed because I see it in disk management in windows, grub is still not giving any video signal (the only thing that appears in the screen is the asus motherboard logo like if it was loading), I know there are some booting options or something you can configure in grub pressing E but I have never modified it, I saw that once and I didn't understand anything, but knowing manjaro is installed I'm pretty sure it's a problem with grub.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred I don't have ubuntu or any debian based system, I have manjaro and windows, so I don't know if there's something like the boot repair for windows that is the only system I can access right now and I don't know if the windows subsystem for linux would help because of being and OS within an OS.

Comment: Boot-Repair works with most Linux. Does manjaro not have a live installer?